# Problem with handling HTTP HEAD and GET in the same method in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, get

I have a problem with a Spring Boot REST controller - I'm trying to get it to serve both GET and HEAD methods at the same endpoint (as it theoretically should - supposedly, making a method respond to GET automatically enables HEAD as well).

The issue is that my GET method returns a response with body - something HEAD should never do. Thus, Spring hiccups when I try to HEAD into my endpoint and I'm all out of ideas why.

My controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{ipAddress}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<ExitNode> getNode(@PathVariable("ipAddress") String ip) {
    if (validateIp(ip)) {
        if (!nodeCheckerService.checkNodeIp(ip)) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(nodeCheckerService.getNode(ip));
        }
    } else return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();

}
```

Everything works fine when I HEAD into the endpoint with a malformed parameter, I get 400 Bad Request and everything's fine. The only problem is with the scenario in which GET returns a body and HEAD should not.

EDIT:

It turned out that Postman was the problem - it didn't parse the response correctly. Installing Insomnia and checking the endpoint proved that the code is OK.

Comment: Why you can not create second endpoint with mapping Head method? You will have two similar method implementations with another request method.

Comment: I tried doing that at first, it didn't work. the result is: `Resolved [IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/192.42.116.20'`
I believe it's due to implicit Spring mapping of HEAD to GET-enabled methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable your logging to show you the mappings.
With mine enabled I see the follwing;

[image]

To enable logging add `logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE` to your `application.properties`

My Restful endpoint.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public ResponseEntity<User> user(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.userService.getUser(userId));
    }

}
```

See postman screenshots below showing success when doing a GET or HEAD to the same endpoint and with same `@PathVariable`

Get request with response body:
[image]

HEAD request with no response body:
[image]

Comment: I added explicit HEAD mapping, my trace logs look like this:

`2018-12-07 11:17:30.543 TRACE 23302 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
 c.m.t.c.NodeCheckerController:
 {[GET, HEAD] /{ipAddress}}: getNode(String)`


Sadly, Postman requests still fail

Comment: Check in your logs for a failure message. Do you have security enabled?

Comment: This is interesting, in the logs i get:


`o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [3fc8c670] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2018-12-07 11:27:35.643 TRACE 24055 --- [or-http-epoll-3] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [3fc8c670] Handling completed`

but Postman gives me errors

Comment: There should also be a line with the follwing `HEAD "/user/3", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'` and a line beneath it with `Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.tut.user.dto.User> com.tut.user.UserController.user(java.lang.String)`

Comment: There is `HTTP HEAD "/192.42.116.20", headers={masked}
2018-12-07 11:27:35.581 DEBUG 24055 --- [or-http-epoll-3] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [3fc8c670] Mapped to public` (blah-blah-blah), but I exceeded comment character limit with it ;)
Does it mean that there's a problem with my Postman, rather than with my code?

Comment: One other thing you can do is open Postman Console and check its logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184869/discussion-between-michael-and-rentius2407).